# Postgres view takes ages to execute

Tags: postgresql

I have created a view that I use to generate some reports afterwards.
When first creating it, I used to have a small amount of data and couldn't notice any issues.

The view now takes forever to load and leads to a lot of performance issues.
I tried to limit the view this way:

```
WHERE date_part('year'::text, e.date) >= date_part('year'::text, CURRENT_DATE - '1 year'::interval);
```

It unfortunately did not help at all.
Is there an efficient way to speed up my query?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.v_lpr
AS WITH e AS (
         SELECT e_1.carpark_id,
            e_1.event_time AS date,
            e_1.device_type,
            e_1.event_type,
            e_1.ticket_type,
            sum(
                CASE
                    WHEN e_1.count > 0 THEN e_1.count
                    ELSE 1
                END) AS sum_event,
            e_1.licenseplatekey
           FROM events e_1
          GROUP BY e_1.carpark_id, e_1.event_type, e_1.device_type, e_1.ticket_type, e_1.event_time, e_1.licenseplatekey
        )
 SELECT e.carpark_id,
    e.date,
    e.device_type,
    COALESCE(ddt.description, 'Unknown'::character varying) AS device_type_name,
    e.event_type,
    COALESCE(det.description, 'Unknown'::character varying) AS event_type_name,
    e.ticket_type,
    COALESCE(dtt.description, 'Other'::character varying) AS ticket_type_name,
    e.sum_event AS count,
    e.licenseplatekey,
    d.country,
    d.state,
    d.district,
    df.facilityname,
    df.tenantname
   FROM e
     JOIN dim_licenseplate d ON d.key = e.licenseplatekey
     JOIN dimfacility df ON df.facilityid = e.carpark_id AND e.date >= date(df.scd_start) AND (e.date < date(df.scd_end) OR df.scd_end IS NULL)
     LEFT JOIN dimtype dtt ON dtt.typeid = e.ticket_type AND dtt.mapping_type::text = 'ticket_type'::text
     LEFT JOIN dimtype ddt ON ddt.typeid = e.device_type AND ddt.mapping_type::text = 'device_type'::text
     LEFT JOIN dimtype det ON det.typeid = e.event_type AND det.mapping_type::text = 'event_type'::text;
```

---

**Query Plan** (https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/lGl)

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=10060558.48..11195587.02 rows=5775196 width=204) (actual time=85580.589..507072.608 rows=6734265 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (e.event_type = det.typeid)
  Buffers: shared hit=6373 read=1118955, temp read=1251698 written=1668112
  CTE e
    ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=7492458.49..10060413.80 rows=6764099 width=40) (actual time=85578.911..256822.632 rows=67400480 loops=1)
          Group Key: e_1.carpark_id, e_1.event_type, e_1.device_type, e_1.ticket_type, e_1.event_time, e_1.licenseplatekey
          Buffers: shared hit=6289 read=1118955, temp read=1251698 written=1253441
          ->  Gather Merge  (cost=7492458.49..9756029.35 rows=13528198 width=40) (actual time=85578.901..211729.452 rows=67431826 loops=1)
                Workers Planned: 2
                Workers Launched: 2
                Buffers: shared hit=6289 read=1118955, temp read=1251698 written=1253441
                ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=7491458.47..8193539.61 rows=6764099 width=40) (actual time=84935.312..121437.041 rows=22477275 loops=3)
                      Group Key: e_1.carpark_id, e_1.event_type, e_1.device_type, e_1.ticket_type, e_1.event_time, e_1.licenseplatekey
                      Buffers: shared hit=6289 read=1118955, temp read=1251698 written=1253441
                      ->  Sort  (cost=7491458.47..7561951.82 rows=28197340 width=36) (actual time=84935.300..103478.557 rows=22548366 loops=3)
                            Sort Key: e_1.carpark_id, e_1.event_type, e_1.device_type, e_1.ticket_type, e_1.event_time, e_1.licenseplatekey
                            Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 947672kB
                            Buffers: shared hit=6289 read=1118955, temp read=1251698 written=1253441
                            ->  Result  (cost=0.00..1689104.77 rows=28197340 width=36) (actual time=0.066..15116.298 rows=22548366 loops=3)
                                  Buffers: shared hit=6203 read=1118955
                                  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1407131.37 rows=28197340 width=36) (actual time=0.065..11417.413 rows=22548366 loops=3)
                                        Buffers: shared hit=6203 read=1118955
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events e_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=3)
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_01 e_1_1  (cost=0.00..27341.93 rows=538092 width=36) (actual time=0.063..187.542 rows=430474 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=128 read=21833
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_02 e_1_2  (cost=0.00..24481.30 rows=482030 width=36) (actual time=0.448..160.483 rows=385624 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=128 read=19533
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_03 e_1_3  (cost=0.00..27685.44 rows=544444 width=36) (actual time=0.076..167.997 rows=435555 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=128 read=22113
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_04 e_1_4  (cost=0.00..24099.90 rows=473690 width=36) (actual time=0.080..146.110 rows=378952 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=128 read=19235
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_05 e_1_5  (cost=0.00..24558.35 rows=484635 width=36) (actual time=0.095..153.181 rows=387708 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=128 read=19584
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_06 e_1_6  (cost=0.00..26523.80 rows=525080 width=36) (actual time=0.077..175.118 rows=420064 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=21177
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_07 e_1_7  (cost=0.00..25321.24 rows=502424 width=36) (actual time=0.099..158.335 rows=401939 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=20201
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_08 e_1_8  (cost=0.00..27389.49 rows=542949 width=36) (actual time=0.116..174.982 rows=434359 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=21864
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_09 e_1_9  (cost=0.00..26073.71 rows=516771 width=36) (actual time=0.103..166.982 rows=413417 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=20810
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_10 e_1_10  (cost=0.00..27452.47 rows=545148 width=36) (actual time=0.071..175.492 rows=436118 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=21905
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_11 e_1_11  (cost=0.00..27293.67 rows=535167 width=36) (actual time=0.072..174.818 rows=428133 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=21846
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2018_12 e_1_12  (cost=0.00..27826.48 rows=540748 width=36) (actual time=0.108..177.344 rows=432599 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=22323
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_01 e_1_13  (cost=0.00..28930.51 rows=572751 width=36) (actual time=0.112..183.352 rows=458201 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=23107
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_02 e_1_14  (cost=0.00..27237.47 rows=542248 width=36) (actual time=0.072..174.700 rows=433798 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=21719
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_03 e_1_15  (cost=0.00..29731.53 rows=591053 width=36) (actual time=0.106..192.812 rows=472843 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=23725
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_04 e_1_16  (cost=0.00..27408.80 rows=545680 width=36) (actual time=0.075..170.280 rows=436544 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=21856
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_05 e_1_17  (cost=0.00..29647.14 rows=590814 width=36) (actual time=0.094..186.307 rows=472651 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=23643
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_06 e_1_18  (cost=0.00..27774.97 rows=551497 width=36) (actual time=0.118..178.236 rows=441197 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=22164
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_07 e_1_19  (cost=0.00..29152.86 rows=580286 width=36) (actual time=0.097..184.164 rows=464229 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=23254
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_08 e_1_20  (cost=0.00..28940.58 rows=576558 width=36) (actual time=0.072..193.012 rows=461247 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=23079
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_09 e_1_21  (cost=0.00..28803.81 rows=574881 width=36) (actual time=0.075..185.001 rows=459905 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=22959
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_10 e_1_22  (cost=0.00..31280.18 rows=622418 width=36) (actual time=0.072..197.873 rows=497934 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=24960
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_11 e_1_23  (cost=0.00..34005.10 rows=673210 width=36) (actual time=0.084..211.443 rows=538568 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=27177
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2019_12 e_1_24  (cost=0.00..34861.76 rows=688076 width=36) (actual time=0.074..228.706 rows=550461 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=27885
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_01 e_1_25  (cost=0.00..32485.37 rows=644137 width=36) (actual time=0.071..202.208 rows=515309 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=25948
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_02 e_1_26  (cost=0.00..31654.59 rows=627759 width=36) (actual time=0.075..188.000 rows=502207 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=25281
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_03 e_1_27  (cost=0.00..20041.85 rows=396985 width=36) (actual time=0.135..122.292 rows=317588 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=15976
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_04 e_1_28  (cost=0.00..10333.11 rows=205111 width=36) (actual time=0.075..66.141 rows=164089 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=8186
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_05 e_1_29  (cost=0.00..19341.51 rows=383051 width=36) (actual time=0.074..129.225 rows=306441 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=15415
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_06 e_1_30  (cost=0.00..24443.33 rows=483733 width=36) (actual time=0.078..162.250 rows=386987 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=19510
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_07 e_1_31  (cost=0.00..28273.57 rows=561657 width=36) (actual time=0.077..172.975 rows=449326 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=22561
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_08 e_1_32  (cost=0.00..28377.88 rows=563188 width=36) (actual time=0.107..185.493 rows=450550 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=22650
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_09 e_1_33  (cost=0.00..29849.43 rows=592443 width=36) (actual time=0.116..180.517 rows=473954 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=23829
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_10 e_1_34  (cost=0.00..30887.97 rows=613598 width=36) (actual time=0.083..197.719 rows=490878 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=24656
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_11 e_1_35  (cost=0.00..24920.20 rows=495220 width=36) (actual time=0.106..160.860 rows=396176 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=19872
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2020_12 e_1_36  (cost=0.00..20743.41 rows=413641 width=36) (actual time=0.128..128.392 rows=330913 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=16511
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_01 e_1_37  (cost=0.00..13223.51 rows=262851 width=36) (actual time=0.070..88.114 rows=210281 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=10499
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_02 e_1_38  (cost=0.00..13419.72 rows=266672 width=36) (actual time=0.075..82.828 rows=213338 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=10657
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_03 e_1_39  (cost=0.00..20760.23 rows=417123 width=36) (actual time=0.069..132.068 rows=333698 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=16493
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_04 e_1_40  (cost=0.00..18513.66 rows=371566 width=36) (actual time=0.088..115.614 rows=297253 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=14702
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_05 e_1_41  (cost=0.00..22992.24 rows=461124 width=36) (actual time=0.078..156.359 rows=368899 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=18285
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_06 e_1_42  (cost=0.00..32086.47 rows=653047 width=36) (actual time=0.106..211.789 rows=522438 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=25460
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_07 e_1_43  (cost=0.00..35158.22 rows=717622 width=36) (actual time=0.107..224.169 rows=574097 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=27886
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_08 e_1_44  (cost=0.00..36240.32 rows=741232 width=36) (actual time=0.076..236.441 rows=592985 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=28732
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_09 e_1_45  (cost=0.00..36505.14 rows=748614 width=36) (actual time=0.065..230.759 rows=598893 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=28923
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_10 e_1_46  (cost=0.00..43014.50 rows=894550 width=36) (actual time=0.085..276.106 rows=715643 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=33973
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_11 e_1_47  (cost=0.00..40632.53 rows=841652 width=36) (actual time=0.077..258.176 rows=673459 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=32120
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2021_12 e_1_48  (cost=0.00..42952.06 rows=894306 width=36) (actual time=0.100..268.463 rows=715962 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=33913
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2022_01 e_1_49  (cost=0.00..36789.60 rows=765160 width=36) (actual time=0.072..239.944 rows=612128 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=29042
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2022_02 e_1_50  (cost=0.00..37959.46 rows=794046 width=36) (actual time=0.078..263.473 rows=635949 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=29923
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events_2022_03 e_1_51  (cost=0.00..1709.01 rows=46601 width=36) (actual time=0.024..8.813 rows=26407 loops=3)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=1243
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=142.62..1119690.02 rows=5775196 width=146) (actual time=85580.537..503667.299 rows=6734265 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (e.device_type = ddt.typeid)
        Buffers: shared hit=2318 read=376956, temp read=424087 written=839346
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=140.55..1104206.82 rows=5775196 width=127) (actual time=85580.506..501171.677 rows=6734265 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (e.ticket_type = dtt.typeid)
              Buffers: shared hit=2317 read=376956, temp read=424087 written=839346
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=138.24..1088723.38 rows=5775196 width=108) (actual time=85580.434..498639.758 rows=6734265 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (e.licenseplatekey = d.key)
                    Buffers: shared hit=2316 read=376956, temp read=424087 written=839346
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=102.45..1073458.17 rows=5775196 width=71) (actual time=85579.980..490328.909 rows=67367271 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (e.carpark_id = df.facilityid)
                          Join Filter: ((e.date >= date(df.scd_start)) AND ((e.date < date(df.scd_end)) OR (df.scd_end IS NULL)))
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 648583247
                          Buffers: shared hit=2301 read=376956, temp read=424087 written=839346
                          ->  CTE Scan on e  (cost=0.00..135281.98 rows=6764099 width=40) (actual time=85578.915..298598.190 rows=67400480 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=2235 read=376956, temp read=424087 written=839346
                          ->  Hash  (cost=82.20..82.20 rows=1620 width=55) (actual time=1.026..1.027 rows=1639 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 161kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=66
                                ->  Seq Scan on dimfacility df  (cost=0.00..82.20 rows=1620 width=55) (actual time=0.026..0.648 rows=1639 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=66
                    ->  Hash  (cost=24.24..24.24 rows=924 width=41) (actual time=0.430..0.431 rows=924 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 76kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=15
                          ->  Seq Scan on dim_licenseplate d  (cost=0.00..24.24 rows=924 width=41) (actual time=0.016..0.211 rows=924 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=15
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.95..1.95 rows=29 width=23) (actual time=0.061..0.062 rows=29 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=1
                    ->  Seq Scan on dimtype dtt  (cost=0.00..1.95 rows=29 width=23) (actual time=0.015..0.026 rows=29 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((mapping_type)::text = 'ticket_type'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 47
                          Buffers: shared hit=1
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.95..1.95 rows=9 width=23) (actual time=0.022..0.023 rows=9 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
              Buffers: shared hit=1
              ->  Seq Scan on dimtype ddt  (cost=0.00..1.95 rows=9 width=23) (actual time=0.009..0.018 rows=9 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((mapping_type)::text = 'device_type'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 67
                    Buffers: shared hit=1
  ->  Hash  (cost=1.95..1.95 rows=9 width=23) (actual time=0.041..0.042 rows=9 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        Buffers: shared hit=1
        ->  Seq Scan on dimtype det  (cost=0.00..1.95 rows=9 width=23) (actual time=0.032..0.037 rows=9 loops=1)
              Filter: ((mapping_type)::text = 'event_type'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 67
              Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning time: 4.618 ms
Execution time: 508178.331 ms
```

---

**Indexes on source table**

- Tablename: Events (with partitions e.g. events_2021_01, events_2021_02, etc)
- I also just saw that I have indexes till 2021_07 only, maybe it could be the cause?

````
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX events_pkey1 ON public.events USING btree (id);

CREATE INDEX idx_duration_entry ON public.events USING btree (card_nr) WHERE ((device_type = 1) AND ((event_type = 2) OR (event_type = 12)) AND ((manufacturer)::text ~~ 'DESIGNA_ABACUS%'::text));

CREATE INDEX idx_duration_exit ON public.events USING btree (card_nr) WHERE ((device_type = 2) AND ((event_type = 2) OR (event_type = 12)) AND ((manufacturer)::text ~~ 'DESIGNA_ABACUS%'::text));

------------------------------------------------------
These indexes are repeated on all partition tables till 2021_07.

CREATE INDEX idx_carpark_events_2018_01 ON public.events_2018_01 USING btree (carpark_id, date_part('year'::text, event_time), date_part('week'::text, event_time), date_part('day'::text, event_time), event_type);

CREATE INDEX idx_events_2018_01 ON public.events_2018_01 USING btree (event_time);
    
CREATE INDEX idx_events_manufacturer_2018_01 ON public.events_2018_01 USING btree (event_time DESC, manufacturer);
    
CREATE INDEX idx_carpark_events_2018_02 ON public.events_2018_02 USING btree (carpark_id, date_part('year'::text, event_time), date_part('week'::text, event_time), date_part('day'::text, event_time), event_type);```


**Source Table DDL**


    CREATE TABLE public.events (
        id int8 NOT NULL,
        odb_created_at timestamp NOT NULL,
        event_time timestamp NOT NULL,
        device_type int4 NOT NULL,
        event_type int4 NOT NULL,
        ticket_type int4 NOT NULL,
        card_nr varchar(100) NULL,
        count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
        manufacturer varchar(200) NULL,
        carpark_id int8 NULL,
        licenseplatekey int4 NULL,
        CONSTRAINT events_pkey1 PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
    CREATE INDEX idx_duration_entry ON public.events USING btree (card_nr) WHERE ((device_type = 1) AND ((event_type = 2) OR (event_type = 12)) AND ((manufacturer)::text ~~ 'DESIGNA_ABACUS%'::text));
    CREATE INDEX idx_duration_exit ON public.events USING btree (card_nr) WHERE ((device_type = 2) AND ((event_type = 2) OR (event_type = 12)) AND ((manufacturer)::text ~~ 'DESIGNA_ABACUS%'::text));
    
    -- Table Triggers
    
    create trigger events_partition_trigger before
    insert
        on
        public.events for each row execute procedure events_partition_function();
````

Comment: Please post the query plan of using the view

Comment: Do you have an index on the `date` column (and what data type is it)

Comment: I just posted the query plan as formatted text, as well as the DDLs for all indexes and the table structure!

Comment: "... that I use to generate some reports afterwards ..." – are you running other queries on this view in order to generate those reports?

Comment: @DavidAldridge I use this view as source and build the reports using Tableau. All what Tableau then does is a ```select*from view```.

Comment: It looks like there's an "external merge" in the building of the CTE result, and that stage alone takes 250 seconds. Some memory tuning of the instance to eliminate that disk sort might be beneficial. If the events data is static once if has been entered, consider storing the aggregated result for each partition of that table so you don't have to re-aggregate it every time this query runs.

Comment: @DavidAldridge thanks for the hint. I was able to reduce the run time from 20 min to 3 min by doing some memory tuning. It's still not fast enough, but I'm getting there :)

Comment: I expect newer versions of Postgres to unwrap the CTE. If not: rewrite the CTE into a subquery, or (temp) view. And don't use non-sargable functions in WHERE or ON clauses.

Answer (score 2):

The condition `date_part('year'::text, e.date) ...` can't make use of an index on the `date` column.

If you only want rows from the current year, use:

```
WHERE e.date >= date_trunc('year', CURRENT_DATE);
```

`date_trunc('year', CURRENT_DATE)` returns the start of "this year" (January, 1st)

If you want rows from this year and last year you can use:

```
WHERE e.date >= date_trunc('year', CURRENT_DATE) - interval '1 year';
```

---

The `OR` condition in the join is also likely a performance killer.

You can avoid the OR in this condition:

```
e.date >= date(df.scd_start) AND (e.date < date(df.scd_end) OR df.scd_end IS NULL)
```

by using a daterange that automatically treats `null` in the upper end as "unbounded"

```
e.date <@ daterange(df.scd_start::date, df.scd_end::date)
```

And possibly create an index on that daterange:

```
create index on dimfacility 
   using gist (daterange(scd_start::date, scd_end::date))
```

---

If `e.date` is not a `date` but a `timestamp` and the `scd_start` and `scd_end` are also timestamps, then use a `tsrange`:

```
e.date <@ tsrange(df.scd_start, df.scd_end)

create index on dimfacility 
   using gist (tsrange(scd_start, scd_end))
```

Comment: thank you. I'm having troubles with the daterange suggestion. The error says: ```operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone <@ daterange
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.```

Comment: i assumed a column named `date` would contain a `date`. In that case, use a timestamp range: `e.date <@ tsrange(df.scd_start, df.scd_end)` (assuming that `scd_start` and `scd_end` are defined as `timestamp`

Comment: Thank you. Performance went from ~20m to 3m 19s with the Postgres Tuning, reducing the amount of data didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause is not sargable due to the fact that you modify the value in the column.

```
WHERE date_part('year'::text, e.date) ...
```

So no index can be used.

Rewrite your WHERE clause to be sargable like this :

```
WHERE e.date >= CAST(CAST(date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) -1 AS CHAR(4) ||'-01-01' AS DATE)
```

Comment: Hi @SQLpro, this results in  ERROR: syntax error at or near "||"

Comment: There is no `year()` function in Postgres.

Comment: Sorry I haven't a PG under my hand when I give this predicate. I have modify the code